# Deploying Node.js application in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have developed a `node.js` application and it is working fine locally.

Now, after that I deployed the application in `Heroku` I am getting some `HTTP 404 errors` in the browser console.

My understanding is that the reason for this issue is caused by the *node*  `package.json` modules. In fact, the **outer** `package.json` is installed successfully but the node modules mentioned in the **client** folder is not installed.

**Q:** Any idea about what is necessary to modify (or to do) to make the client node modules as installed?

The image below depicts my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you push your code to Heroku, Heroku will look for the `package.json` file in the ROOT of your project. Heroku will then install those dependencies.

In your case, because you have multiple `package.json` files, Heroku isn't seeing the ones nested in sub-folders of your project.

The best option you have is to list all dependencies in your top-level `package.json` file. You could also create your own [Heroku Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to customize the Heroku deployment procedure, but I strongly recommend AGAINST doing this (it will be a nightmare to maintain over time).

Another option in your case (which might be good depending on how large your team is) would be to move your client-side code into it's own Git project, and have that deployed separately to a static hosting provider like Amazon S3, or something similar. This would then let you deploy your backend project directly to Heroku, while not having to worry about any front-end logic at all.